# Oracle APEX calculated field is not shown on the report

Tags: apex, oracle-apex-5.1

In my report I am pulling data from 2 tables and I want to display a calculated column. If I run the query in SQL Workshop, it works as desired but in the report calculated column does not get displayed.
Can annyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Perhaps there is a better way to accomplish what I want?

```
select "T1"."Table2_ID",
   "T2"."Title",
   "T1"."PRICE",
   "T1"."QTY",
   TO_CHAR("T1"."QTY" * "T1"."PRICE", '$999.99') AS TOTAL_PRICE    
  from "Table1" "T1",
   "Table2" "T2"
  where "T1"."Table2_ID" = "T2"."ID"
```

Column type on the report is listed as plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it an interactive report? If so,

- run the report
- go to "Actions" menu
- Columns
- include the newly added column into the *displayed* column list

If not, what is it?

Comment: Thank you! It is an interactive report and your answer worked